# Finding corresponding bins between two data sets

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, binning

So I have two data sets which overlap in their parameter space:
[image: two overlapping datasets]

I want to bin up the red set and find the standard deviation of each bin.  Then for each point in the blue set, I want to find which red bin that point corresponds to and grab the standard deviation calculated for that bin.

So far, I've been using scipy.statistics.binned_2d, but I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
# given numpy recarrays red_set and blue_set with columns x,y,values

nbins = 50

red_bins = scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d(red_set['x'],
                                           red_set['y'],
                                           red_set['values'],
                                           statistic = np.std,
                                           bins = nbins)

blue_bins = scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d(blue_set['x']
                                            blue_set['y']
                                            blue_set['values']
                                            statistic = count,
                                            bins = red_bins[1],red_bins[2])
```

Now, I don't know how to get the value of the corresponding red bin for each blue point.  I know that scipy.statistics.binned_2d's third return is a binnumber for each input data point, but I don't know how to translate that to the actual calculated statistic (standard deviation in this example).

I know that the blue set is getting binned exactly the same as the red (a quick plot will confirm this).  It *seems* like it should be totally straightforward to grab the corresponding red bin, but I can't figure it out.

Let me know if I can make my question clearer

Comment: Are red_set['x'] and blue_set['x'] the same? How about red_set['y'] and blue_set['y']? If both are identical, just chose bins = nbins in both cases and you are fine. Then red_bins[0][i,j] gives you the value corresponding to blue_bins[0][i,j].

Comment: How do you mean same? They do not have identical values, as you can see in the plot, but they refer to the same two parameters

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you specify the same `range` when binning the data. In that way, the corresponding indices of the bins will be consistent. I've used the lower level numpy function hist2d, extension to standard deviations can be done in the same way using `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d`,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Setup random data
red = np.random.randn(100,2)
blue = np.random.randn(100,2)

#plot
plt.plot(red[:,0],red[:,1],'r.')
plt.plot(blue[:,0],blue[:,1],'b.')

#Specify limits of binned data
xmin = -3.; xmax = 3.
ymin = -3.; ymax = 3.

#Bin data using hist2d
rbins, xrb, yrb = np.histogram2d(red[:,0],red[:,1],bins=10,range=[[xmin,xmax],[ymin,ymax]])
bbins, xbb, ybb = np.histogram2d(blue[:,0],blue[:,1],bins=10,range=[[xmin,xmax],[ymin,ymax]])

#Check that bins correspond to the same positions in space
assert all(xrb == xbb)
assert all(yrb == ybb)

#Obtain centers of the bins and plots difference
xc = xrb[:-1] + 0.5 * (xrb[1:] - xrb[:-1])
yc = yrb[:-1] + 0.5 * (yrb[1:] - yrb[:-1])
plt.contourf(xc, yc, rbins-bbins, alpha=0.4)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing I'm confused about is that when I bin my second data set, I explicitly use the same bins created for the first:

`blue_bins = scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d(blue_set['x']
                                            blue_set['y']
                                            blue_set['values']
                                            statistic = count,
                                            bins = red_bins[1],red_bins[2])`

What does specifying the range do that specifying the bins doesn't?

Comment: Bins as an integer specify the number of bins to split the domain into, with this you need the range to specify the min and max values to stretch the bins over. Specifying the locations of the bins based on a previous `binned_statistic_2d` should work too...